# What is the threshold of sequence# difference between primary and standby database when checking replication status?

Tags: oracle

I am checking if `replication` is working properly in `standby database`. For this, i calculate the difference between `sequence#` of `v$log_history`.

I am using this query to find the max sequence number.

```
select max(sequence#) a from v$log_history where FIRST_TIME > SYSDATE -1;
```

Executed the query in `primary` and `standby` database and then calculate the difference.

What is the threshold value of the difference from which i can decide if the replication works properly or not?